# Emacs doesn't have dialog boxes when compiled with LUCID

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, ubuntu-12.04, emacs24

After downloading Emacs 24.2 and compiling under (K)ubuntu 12.04 with

./configure --with-x-toolkit=lucid
make
sudo make install

there are no dialog boxes (e.g. file selection or font selection). When clicking on open file, "Find File" in minibuffer appears.

Do I need additional libraries for that or is it only possible with GTK?

Thanks

Comment: I would say that's not a bug, it's a feature ;-)

Comment: yes, I thought it was useful for browsing files only with the mouse, it can be done with dired though but one has to get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

File and font dialogs are only implemented for GTK, Mac/Gnustep and Windows.